# How to write regex for "cmd param1, param2, paramm"

Tags: java, regex

How to write `regex` for `cmd` `$param1`, `$param2`, ...., `$paramn?

My solution would be like this but it's only 4 params

```
 "(\\w+)\\s*(\\$\\w+)*,*\\s*(\\$\\w+)*,*\\s*(\\$\\w+)*,*\\s*(\\$\\w+)*"
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are only intrested in the actual params, you only need (\w*), this will give you an array of all Words without Dollars.

If you need the Dollars use: (\$\w*)

You can test it out on [regexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
"^\\w+\\s+(\\$[^\\,^\\s,^\\$]+\\s*,\\s*)*\\$[^\\,^\\s,^\\$]+$"
```